How to center the login structure in the middle of the page?
How to center the login structure in the middle of the page?


import React, {useState} from 'react'
import "./Signin.css"

const Signin = () => {
    const [addClass, setaddClass] = useState("");
  return (
     <div className={`container ${addClass}`} id='container'>
         <div className='form-container sign-up-container'>
            <form>
                <h1>Create Account</h1>
                <input type="text" placeholder='name'/>
                <input type="email" placeholder='email'/>
                <input type="password" placeholder='password'/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>

            </form>
         </div>
            <div className="form-container sign-in-container">
              <form>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <input type="email" placeholder='email'/>
                <input type="password" placeholder='password'/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
              <div className="overlay-container">
                 <div className="overlay">
                      <div className="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                        <button className="ghost" id="signIn" onClick={() =>setaddClass("")}>Go to Login
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                        <button className="ghost" id="signUp" onClick={() =>setaddClass("right-panel-active")} >Go to Register</button>
                      </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
     </div>
  )
}

export default Signin
.container {
    background: #f6f5f7;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: -20px 0 50px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  
  button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #2c143e;
    background-color: #2c143e;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
  }
  
  button:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  
  button:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  
  button.ghost {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  form {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
  }
  
  .form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  
  .sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
  }
  
  @keyframes show {
    0%,
    49.99% {
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  
    50%,
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 5;
    }
  }
  
  .overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  
  .container.right-panel-active .overlay-container {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  
  .overlay {
    background: #2c143e;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #2c143e, #2c143e);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c143e, #2c143e);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  
  .overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
  }
  
  .container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  
  .overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  
  .container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }



import React, {useState} from 'react'
import "./Signin.css"
const Signin = () => {
const [addClass, setaddClass] = useState("");
return (
<div className={container ${addClass}} id='container'>


Create Account



Submit
        </form>
     </div>
        <div className="form-container sign-in-container">
          <form>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input type="email" placeholder='email'/>
            <input type="password" placeholder='password'/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
          <div className="overlay-container">
             <div className="overlay">
                  <div className="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                    <button className="ghost" id="signIn" onClick={() =>setaddClass("")}>Go to Login
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                    <button className="ghost" id="signUp" onClick={() =>setaddClass("right-panel-active")} >Go to Register</button>
                  </div>
             </div>
          </div>
 </div>

)
}
export default Signin
This is the result I have so far:
Login-screenshot

usually, themes like bootstrap have already well designed login/registration pages. If you're new to CSS/HTML world, better use a theme like that, and modify logo/other things as per your needs.

This question is similar to: How can I horizontally center an element?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I want to show you two methods. Both methods fulfill your request. You can choose the one you need. We add the flex property and justifiy-content:center properties as display. Thus, your form is placed in the center.
First, wrap your container class with a container div. Make a css assignment to it. The example is in the code below.
React Code:
return (
<div className='wrapper'>
    <div className={`container ${addClass}`} id='container'>
          //your codes
       </div>
 </div>
)

CSS code:
  .wrapper{    
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

The second method is that since your container class is already in a root, you can apply this css on the root without add any wrapper.
CSS Code
  #root{    
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }


Hi, I would really like to thank you as your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

You're welcome, I'm glad to help. It will help others if you approve the answer. @IsmaelSanchez

display: flexbox; and justify-content: center; in CSS is a good way to center the login structure. Read this post for more info.
Code:
    .form-container {
        display: flexbox;
        justify-content: center;
        /* add rest of styling code */
    }

Warning! Below Deprecated!
The center tag can be used to center the text horizontally. The downside to using this is that it is deprecated and may be removed in future versions of HTML.

Ismael Sanchez
Your CSS was a bit off. In order to show your Signin component on the middle of your screen you can use this CSS
 html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


.container {
  background: #f6f5f7;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw; /* Full screen width */
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* Avoids scrollbars */
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #2c143e;
  background-color: #2c143e;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px 45px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}

button:active {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

form {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 50px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 480px;
}

.form-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%; /* Full width of container */
}

.sign-in-container {
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container {
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 5;
  animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
  0%,
  49.99% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  50%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
  }
}

.overlay-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.overlay {
  background: #2c143e;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #2c143e, #2c143e);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c143e, #2c143e);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
  transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
  transform: translateX(20%);
}

I personally use tailwindcss which is much easier than making a CSS file for each component.
